# Brightness buttons are not working at all

Tags: 13.04, brightness, acer, button, media-buttons

I have asked this question multiple times. i have an acer 5750 laptop running Ubuntu 13.04 and all of a sudden then brightness buttons wont adjust the computers brightness. it was working not too long ago but one day when i booted up it all of a sudden wouldent work... i really need these buttons as it prevents me from going to settings and changing it from there... Someone please help me i really need these buttons

Answer (score 0):

I have had this same problem myself, as I am currently running an Acer Aspire M5-481T (Timeline U) on Ubuntu 13.04 and the problem has been with me on 12.10 as well. So it is likely an issue with an Acer driver (same goes with your multi-touch gesture issue. Mine also doesn’t work, nor does my SD card reader. And I also have to press "fn+Alt+F7" in order to use the trackpad upon start up) What I do know is that when I recently installed 13.04 the brightness DID work. I then reinstalled Burg boot-loader, after which the brightness commands stopped working. Possibly just a coincidence. As I have not unistalled to check and see if SD card/ brightness issues are directly caused by the different bootloader.

For me the issue isn't a huge problem and I mostly ignore it. But Somthing that may work out is I have come across this page for my SPECIFIC laptop (not sure if it will work for you). But here is what they said about brightnesss arrows to work:

"
fn+backlight works too!
Go to terminal, log in: su -l
gedit /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
(Ignore the line do not edit this file)
Find the proper bootline which boots your kernel and add
'acpi_backlight=vendor' parameter in kernel options.

It looks like this, I made my entry bold for easy recognition, just add it after the keyboard entry:

```
menuentry 'Fedora (3.1.1-2.fc16.x86_64)' –class fedora –class gnu-linux
–class gnu –class os {
load_video
set gfxpayload=keep
insmod gzio
insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='(hd0,msdos1)'
search –no-floppy –fs-uuid –set=root 8cb738a0-95f4-4fe7-9c42-7d95aa3cc8da
echo 'Loading Fedora (3.1.1-2.fc16.x86_64)'
linux /vmlinuz-3.1.1-2.fc16.x86_64
root=UUID=76b94cf5-3dad-4b63-899e-2c99849fdde3 ro LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8 rd.md=0
rd.lvm=0 rd.dm=0 quiet rhgb rd.luks=0 KEYTABLE=us acpi_backlight=vendor
echo 'Loading initial ramdisk …'
initrd /initramfs-3.1.1-2.fc16.x86_64.img
}
```

Then reboot, and hey presto! Fn+backlight works!
"

Source: http://www.linlap.com/acer_aspire_4830tg_timelinex